# unable to find a valid app electron after installation in windows 10

Tags: node.js

I am getting the error "unable to find a valid app electron after installation in windows 10. How to add package.json in the sources directory.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "asar": "^0.7.2",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.31.0",
    "fs-jetpack": "^0.7.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-copy": "0.0.2",
    "gulp-install": "^0.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-usemin": "^0.3.12",
    "q": "^1.4.1",
    "rcedit": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sequelize": "^3.20.0",
    "tedious": "^1.14.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which operation leads to an "unable to find a valid app electron" error?

Comment: Hi KonstantinA.Magg, i am getting the error at startup.please find the attached error file.

Comment: Please provide more details on what you are trying to do and what your are expecting to happen.

Comment: Hi i am able to sort it out. Thanks for your help. But now i am facing a new issue. My Anjularjs , controller js file are not loading after i installed the app